# How to remove unnamed indices in PDO request?

Tags: php, pdo

A sample result from a database query

```
SomeFile.php:14:
array (size=2)
    0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => int 1
       0 => int 1
    0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => int 2
       0 => int 2
```

How can the 0s (unnamed indice) be removed without manually creating a new array while keeping the name one ('id')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PDOStatement::fetch` and `PDOStatement:fetchAll` methods both have a `$fetch_style` parameter controlling how the returned result looks like. Its default value is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` which returns an array indexed by both column names and their numbers. If you want just the names, use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. See the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) for other possible fetch styles.

Answer (score 1):

By default PDO returns an array indexed by column name and a zero-based array index.

You can return what you want by setting the fetch style to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC as in

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

See [the manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) for more details.